# На что он рушается? Python

Tags: python

> Cause exception while getting updates. Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py",
> line 381, in start_polling
> updates = await self.bot.get_updates(   File "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py",
> line 110, in get_updates
> result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)   File
> "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py",
> line 236, in request
> return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,   File
> "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py",
> line 140, in make_request
> return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())   File
> "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py",
> line 119, in check_result
> exceptions.ConflictError.detect(description)   File "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py",
> line 140, in detect
> raise err(cls.text or description) aiogram.utils.exceptions.TerminatedByOtherGetUpdates: Terminated by
> other getupdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is
> running Cause exception while getting updates. Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py",
> line 381, in start_polling
> updates = await self.bot.get_updates(   File "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py",
> line 110, in get_updates
> result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)   File
> "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py",
> line 236, in request
> return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,   File
> "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py",
> line 140, in make_request
> return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())   File
> "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py",
> line 119, in check_result
> exceptions.ConflictError.detect(description)   File "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py",
> line 140, in detect
> raise err(cls.text or description) aiogram.utils.exceptions.TerminatedByOtherGetUpdates: Terminated by
> other getupdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is
> running Cause exception while getting updates. Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py",
> line 381, in start_polling
> updates = await self.bot.get_updates(   File "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py",
> line 110, in get_updates
> result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)   File
> "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py",
> line 236, in request
> return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,   File
> "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py",
> line 140, in make_request
> return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())   File
> "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py",
> line 119, in check_result
> exceptions.ConflictError.detect(description)   File "C:\Users\Germann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py",
> line 140, in detect
> raise err(cls.text or description) aiogram.utils.exceptions.TerminatedByOtherGetUpdates: Terminated by
> other getupdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is
> running Cause exception while getting updates.

Comment: Приложите пожалуйста к ошибке свой код

Comment: похоже, что на ошибку в коде

Comment: убедитесь, что при получении обновлений работает только один экземпляр бота.